# How to pass Facebook user data to a new activity in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating Facebook Login using custom button. The problem is, how do I pass the Facebook user data (e.g username, email, etc) to a new activity?

Anyway, I would like to pass the user data to Navigation view where there is Username and Email at the top. Currently, the codes below only passing within one activity.

I'm new to mobile app programming and also C#, any help would be much appreciated. Also, please let me know if there's anything wrong with the codes below.

**Login.cs**

```
namespace MyCustomApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "Login", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Login : Activity, IFacebookCallback, GraphRequest.IGraphJSONObjectCallback

    {
        private ICallbackManager mCallBackManager;
        private MyProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

        private TextView mTxtFirstName;
        private TextView mTxtLastName;
        private TextView mTxtName;

        Button facebookButton;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(this.ApplicationContext);

            mProfileTracker = new MyProfileTracker();
            mProfileTracker.mOnProfileChanged += MProfileTracker_mOnProfileChanged;
            mProfileTracker.StartTracking();

        Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle); 
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);

        facebookButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CSbutton); //Custom button
        mTxtFirstName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtFirstName);
        mTxtLastName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLastName);
        mTxtName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);

        mCallBackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();

        LoginManager.Instance.RegisterCallback(mCallBackManager, this);

        facebookButton.Click += (o, e) => 
        {
            if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null && Profile.CurrentProfile != null)
            {
                //The user is logged in through Facebook
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                this.StartActivity(intent);
                this.Finish();
                facebookButton.Text = "Log out";
            }

            else
            {
                //The user is not logged in
                LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(this, new List<string> { "public_profile", "user_friends", "email" });
            }
        };
    }

    private void MProfileTracker_mOnProfileChanged(object sender, OnProfileChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.mProfile != null)
        {
            try
            {
                mTxtFirstName.Text = e.mProfile.FirstName;
                mTxtLastName.Text = e.mProfile.LastName;
                mTxtName.Text = e.mProfile.Name;
                mProfilePic.ProfileId = e.mProfile.Id;

                if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null && Profile.CurrentProfile != null)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                    this.StartActivity(intent);
                    this.Finish();
                    facebookButton.Text = "Log out";
                }
                else
                { facebookButton.Text = "Log in"; }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle error, just in case
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //The user must have logged out
            mTxtFirstName.Text = "First Name";
            mTxtLastName.Text = "Last Name";
            mTxtName.Text = "Name";
            mProfilePic.ProfileId = null;
        }
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Org.Json.JSONObject json, GraphResponse response)
    {
        string data = json.ToString();
        FacebookResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookResult>(data);
    }

    public void OnCancel() 
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnError(FacebookException error)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        LoginResult loginResult = result as LoginResult;
        Console.WriteLine(loginResult.AccessToken.UserId);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallBackManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, (int)resultCode, data);
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        mProfileTracker.StopTracking();
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}

public class MyProfileTracker : ProfileTracker //Listener for profile
{
    public event EventHandler<OnProfileChangedEventArgs> mOnProfileChanged;

    protected override void OnCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile)
    {
        if (mOnProfileChanged != null)
        {
            mOnProfileChanged.Invoke(this, new OnProfileChangedEventArgs(newProfile));
        }
    }
}

public class OnProfileChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Profile mProfile;

    public OnProfileChangedEventArgs(Profile profile) { mProfile = profile; }
}
```